# .match() does'nt returns an array but a string

Tags: javascript

`.match()` wont give an array back with the elements in it?
Instead it's just a string?

```
  var descr = jobs[i].description;
  console.log(typeof descr);
  descr.match(/\b(java|python|javascript|ruby|rails)\b/i);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) *does* return an array (or `null`). How do you display it?

Comment: What does `typeof descr` return (why are you `console.log`ing that)?  `match` doesn't affect the original string, are you sure you're looking at the right variable (the returned array versus the original string)?

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it working

```
  var descr = jobs[i].description;

  var arr = descr.match(/\b(java|python|javascript|ruby|rails)\b/gi);

  if(arr !== null){
    console.log("arr is? " + typeof arr); //<--- will print "object" i dont know why?
    console.log("arr     " + arr);
    console.log("arr [0] " + arr[0]);
    console.log("arr  ..." + arr.length);
  }
```

Comment: `typeof` says "object" when it's an array.  That's just how it's defined.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof